# How can i detect [ in App-delegate ] that user changed view from standard to zoomed in Display settings of iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

As much as i know when we switch between Standard and Zoomed view iphone restarts in background. 
I have some code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method for clearing keychain if its a fresh install.
Now when ever i switch view[standard to zoomed] iOs treats it as a fresh install and clears keychain, thus making my application crash.
Is there anyway to know in code that view is changed so i can stop application from reseting keychain.
Here is the code snippet:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
    launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //clear keychain for every fresh install
    if !Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Keys.kIsFreshInstall) {

        //delete keychain
        print("clearing keychain")
        EMKeychainUtil.clearKeychain()

        // update the flag indicator
        Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:Keys.kIsFreshInstall)
    }

    return true
}
```

UPDATE:

Whenever device restarts UserDefaults are not reseted.

There was a code in my project that was internally clearing the UserDefaults data first and then the check was made for keychain clearing , hence the issue was there.

Comment: Why does this code make your application crash?

Comment: @AaronBrager- Whenever the switch is made iphone restarts thus "Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:Keys.kIsFreshInstall)" this flag is set to false and my keychain is deleted, since my app needs few items from keychain on startup, it does not find it and crashes.

Comment: Since the user may choose to delete items from the keychain any time, you should rewrite your application to check for the keychain items and handle the situation gracefully if they’re missing.

Comment: The user doesn't know about the keychain deletion and has no power to delete it, the app does that on every fresh install, so handling keychain situation gracefully does not lead to the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your appDelegate monitor `UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeScale` property (not `scale`)

The. scale will remain constant but nativeScale will go up / down with the zoom factor set

—

As for observing it:
KVO would not work since any app is killed when changing zoom in settings. You may have to persist it if needed

Comment: Persisting the values of native screen via variables would be very difficult, also saving unnecessary values in keychain is not advised, hence the difficulty in comparison as well. Is there any way of adding OBSERVOR for  UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeScale?

Comment: Yes kvo would be a way BUT changing the scale will terminate your app so no

Comment: Why would it be difficult to persist? Write it to a file or save it in UserDefaults…

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code :

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
```

The scale size will be different when you changed from standard to zoomed.

Hope it will help!

Comment: wrong. "If you enable display zoom, scale remains the same, at 3 (e.g. for 6+), since the intermediate buffer is still rendered at 1 point = 3 pixels. But native scale becomes 2.8. (e.g. for 6+),"